# How do I perform this command in azure powershell on my hdinsight cluster?

Tags: powershell, azure, ssh, azure-hdinsight

I have managed to use this command on my hdinsight when I connect via ssh using azure cli, however I want to create an azure powershell scrip that will run the following command but I can't figure out how. I have tried searching for it online but can't find anything.

```
sudo -HE /usr/bin/anaconda/bin/conda install pandas
```

Answer (score 1):

In this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-customize-cluster-linux?#apply-a-script-action-to-a-running-cluster) see a section titled "Apply a script action to a running cluster from Azure PowerShell". You will need to take your script and put it in blob storage and then have the cluster execute that script ok each node using an HDInsight script action. The nice thing about script actions is that when they do cluster maintenance patching the underlying servers and need to take down a node and bring up a new node (or if you scale the cluster) then it will run the script action on any new nodes.